# LEFT JOIN com AND no Eloquent Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho uma query com Left Join com AND não estou conseguindo implementar isso no laravel 5.

Um trecho da query:

```
LEFT JOIN visitante v ON a.codigo = v.id 
AND v.data BETWEEN '2015-06-01' and '2016-05-31' and v.status = '1'
```

Tentei assim mas nao deu certo:

```
->leftJoin(DB::raw('visitante v ON a.codigo = v.id
AND v.data BETWEEN \'2015-06-01\' and \'2016-05-31\' and v.status = \'1\''))
```

Comment: Dá algum erro? porque não dá certo?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Aparece o erro:
Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::leftJoin(), called in /...Controller.php on line 120 and defined que é nessa linha

Comment: Do jeito que está essa consulta, se pode usar a maneira mais simples fazendo toda a SQL e passando para executar, assim não vai funcionar porque `leftJoin` não usa `DB::Raw` (até onde eu sei), então faça https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries o que está descrito nesse link. Também tem pouca informação para desenvolver uma resposta exata!

Comment: É eu ja tinha visto e nao tem muita informacao vou continuar procurando na Net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Consegui resolver desta forma!**

```
->leftJoin('visitante as v', function($join) 
            {

                $join->on('a.codigo', '=', 'v.id');

                $join->on('v.data','>=',DB::raw("'2015-06-01'"));
                $join->on('v.data','<=',DB::raw("'2016-05-31'"));
                $join->on('v.status','=',DB::raw("'1'"));

            })
```